# Is ruby a pre-requisite to install gem?

Tags: ruby, gem

I need to install `gem` on my Ubuntu 16.04 in order to install `Travis CI CLI`. Is it necessary to install `ruby` before installing `gem`? I literally have no idea about `ruby` and `gem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 16.04 the package `ruby` replaces `rubygems`, among it's installed files is `/usr/bin/gem`. So the answer is no, you just need to install `ruby` as there's no separate package for `gem` anymore.